# Unable to access shared folder on windows via apache on mac

Tags: coldfusion, apache2, virtualhost, coldfusion-9

I am trying to setup a local site on my mac.

The configuration is like this -

Application Server: Coldfusion 9

Webserver: Apache 2

I have got my local site up and running. But in this site, I wish to access the images hosted on my dev server (windows 2003). The images folder is shared and I can mount it from my mac.

I have added the virtual director in my httpd.conf like this -

```
Alias /images/covers/uk "//xxx.xx.x.xx/Imagesfolder/covers/uk/"
<Directory "//xxx.xx.x.xx/Imagesfolder/covers/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>


Alias /images/covers "//xxx.xx.x.xx/Imagesfolder/covers/"
<Directory "//1xxx.xx.x.xx/Imagesfolder/covers/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here xxx.xx.x.xx is the ip of the windows server. Imagesfolder is the name of the shared folder on server.

However, I am not able to access this folder and I am getting 403 error.

Any idea how to fix this please.

Answer (score 0):

You should mount the shared folder on your Mac and configure Apache to use the mounted directory as Alias. Apache cannot access SMB/CIFS shares by URL as you are trying to do.

```
Alias /images "/path/to/mounted/images-directory"
<Directory /path/to/mounted/directory>
  ...
</Directory>
```

I advise you to read Apache's manual to get more in deep details.

Comment: I have mounted it on mac and given the path to the shared directory. see how it is at the moment in the question above. May be you can suggest what is wrong with that path

Comment: I mean ```//xxx.xx.x.xx/Imagesfolder/covers/``` kind of path, it should be something like ```/Users/you/Images/covers```.

What ```xxx.xx.x.xx``` is?